# Ember custom model save

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my application I have a model `post`, it has properties `user_likes` and `user_shares`, a user can share and like a post of course...

a save action results in a PUT for /posts/:id with post as payload, but in my webserver shares and likes have different store strategies, and **I need know what exactly has changed** to save properly, how can I do it with ember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Model` class has a [changedAttributes](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_changedAttributes) method that will tell you what attributes have changed. You can create a `PostAdapter` and override the [updateRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_updateRecord) method to customize the way the data is persisted. Or if it's all going to the same place and you just want to change the JSON format, you can create a `PostSerializer` and override the [serialize](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Serializer.html#method_serialize) method.

Comment: Thanks, changedAttributes is what I'm looking for.